# Regular expression - dont match consecutive chars - C#

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have wasted enough time to construct a regular expressions which matches.

1. starts with [a-z]+
2. ends with [a-z]+
3. in between can have ' or - or both, as many times as user likes ['-]*
4. ' should not be consecutive, similarly - should not be consecutive.

thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: This may be easier to do either with normal string functions or with separate regular expressions... you probably _could_ build an expression to do what you want, but separate statements will be much more readable and maintainable, and not really perform any worse for most use cases.

Comment: @4castle That doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried it in Regex101.  It didn't work.

Comment: @4castle Fails for this input `abc'-'-'abc` ... OP said nothing about the apostrophe and hyphen being balanced.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I see. Fixed: [`^[a-z]+(?:(?:'-)*'?|(?:-')*-?)[a-z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/xA7aU2/1)

Comment: @4castle Next time post to earn some green points :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!.*(?:''|--))[a-z][a-z'-]*[a-z]$
```

You can add `lookahead` for the same.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wV5bD0/2

If length can be `1` or `2` you use

```
^(?!.*(?:''|--))(?=[a-z])[a-z'-]+(?<=[a-z])$
```

Comment: Thanks vks, this has done the trick for me. can you please break it down, so that I can understand how it works. thanks anyway

Comment: @ahsant the only thing i added is `lookahead` which states that it should not match if it finds consective `''` or `--`

Comment: If the min length can be less than 3 (vks regex requires at least 3) you may use a `^(?!.*(?:''|--))\b[a-z'-]+\b$` pattern to allow 1 or more.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah missed......have been away for too long from regex!!